# Sonar vNext: Code Coverage Not Reported, but Coverage File Found

Tags: .net, sonarqube, sonarqube-scan

I'm having an issue with Sonar not reporting code coverage for an application which is being analyzed during a vNext build. Both TFS and Sonar are hosted on-prem and I am using Sonar 6.0. I looked around here and I didn't see any posts with the exact same issue, so I figured I would post to see if anyone has any ideas.

During the build, a unit test suite is ran, which generates a trx file, a coverage file, and a coveragexml file. In the sonar properties field, I point it to those files to use for analysis

```
 /d:sonar.cs.vscoveragexml.reportsPaths="$(Common.TestResultsDirectory)\*.coveragexml" /d:sonar.cs.vstest.reportsPaths="$(Common.TestResultsDirectory)\*.trx"
```

When looking at the build log, it is picking up both those files during Finish Analysis step:

```
2016-10-28T14:31:01.5800405Z 10:31:01.463  Attempting to locate a test    results (.trx) file...

2016-10-28T14:31:01.5800405Z 10:31:01.463  Located a test results file: E:\agent\_work\24\TestResults\tfsbuildagent_BUILD1 2016-10-28 10_30_52.trx
```

and

```
2016-10-28T14:31:15.7254549Z INFO: Parsing the Visual Studio coverage XML report E:\agent\_work\24\TestResults\tfsbuildagent_BUILD1 2016-10-28 10_30_52\In\BUILD1\tfsbuildagent_BUILD1 2016-10-28 10_30_38.coveragexml

2016-10-28T14:31:15.9254749Z INFO: Adding this code coverage report to the cache for later reuse: E:\agent\_work\24\TestResults\tfsbuildagent_BUILD1 2016-10-28 10_30_52\In\BUILD1\tfsbuildagent_BUILD1 2016-10-28 10_30_38.coveragexml
```

But when you look at the application in Sonar, there is no code coverage shown. I can open the coveragexml file, and it looks like it does definitely have coverage data in there. I also had the engineer of the application show me the coverage results in visual studio after they run the test suite, and there is definitely coverage being reported. I just can't figure out why that data isn't being translated into Sonar.

This also poses the question: how exactly is Sonar using the data found in the test result file and coverage XML file? Is it taking the data from those files directly and just using those numbers as part of its result, or is it using a combination of those numbers and data it gets from analyzing the code to calculate final statistics? I've never been able to find a clear answer to this online, not even on Sonar's site. I feel like having a better understanding of that process would also help resolve this issue.

Anyway, if anyone could provide any insight as to possibly why Sonar isn't picking up the data in the coverage file, I would really appreciate it. If you need any additional information, please let me know.

Comment: I've also encountered this issue.  I'm currently looking to solve it myself so if I figure it out I'll let you know.

Comment: did you ever manage to figure this out?  I'm still struggling with it myself.  I did find a bug report on Sonars Jira that mentions issues with the coverage being picked up, but the solution mentioned there made no difference for me.  I thought I'd share it with you anyway just in case it helps you: https://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/SONARMSBRU-262

Comment: Thanks for the link. I'll give it a shot. I haven't had a chance to even look at this since I last posted. If I figure it out, I'll update the post with the solution.

Comment: Quick update: I tried what the link suggested, but I was already using the path $(Common.TestResultsDirectory) so nothing changed.

Comment: Yes that's what I found too - but thought it might be worth a shot for you :)

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix the issue of coverage not being reported, but it may be specific to my case and I'm still not really sure *why* this fixes the issue.

I have to build 2 solutions for this particular applications as part of their build process. One of the solutions contains a test project but the other does not. It seemed the fact that both projects were being built, with only one having tests threw things off.

I checked to make sure that the output of one build was not overwriting the other as well and it was not.

The fix was to create a separate vNext build whose specific purpose is to report to Sonar, and only builds the primary solution and runs it's test suite. Their test suite is only hitting code related to the primary solution, so this works fine for the developer in this case.

Answer (score 0):

I know this problem is old, but I just faced similar problem and perhaps someone will bump into this thread and this could help.

The issue was not in the sonar, but in vstest and .netcore issue with code coverage. The coverage file was empty, and that's why it wasn't picked up for analysis.

To fix this, you need to add to all your csproj files (both test and product) following snippet:

```
 <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp1.1</TargetFramework> 
    <!-- Required in both test/product projects. This is a temporary workaround for https://github.com/microsoft/vstest/issues/800 -->
    <DebugType>pdbonly</DebugType>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

According to: https://github.com/microsoft/vstest/issues/800 it should be fixed, but there are different opinions on this.

In addition, I needed to setup all projects in solution to be built as x64, since in runsettings I had `<TargetPlatform>x64</TargetPlatform>`.